# GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGE NOT WORKING FOR ANDROID 2.3.6

Tags: android, push-notification, cloud, message, google-cloud-messaging

I am not able to to call `onReceive()` method through broadcast receiver in android version 2.3.6.(Working fine in later versions)

My Android.manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="hellomultiscreen" android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="2.2.0" >
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <permission android:name="hellomultiscreen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="hellomultiscreen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <application android:label="Online Booking" >

    <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
        <receiver android:name="hellomultiscreen.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
                <category android:name="hellomultiscreen" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    <service android:name="hellomultiscreen.MyIntentService" enabled="true" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the error on this one?

Comment: onreceive() not firing when sending message through gcm but upper version firing

Comment: Don't write anythin in ALL CAPS - this is a net equivalent to shouting.

Comment: tried but not working...everything same

Answer (score 1):

Based on the manifest you posted, your app's package name is either `hellomultiscreen.cybrain` or `hellomultiscreen`. You should use the correct package name in all three placed in the manifest relevant to GCM (where it says `YOUR_PACKAGE` below):

```
  <permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver android:name="hellomultiscreen.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <!-- Receive the actual message -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
        <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: it was via mistake,actually i am using only hellomultiscreen